# Displaying custom text in a map snippet, Android

Tags: java, android, xml, maps, code-snippets

Ok, I've been at this all day now, I give up trying to get this myself!

I've declared the map and location

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

declared the location

```
static final LatLng SECC = new LatLng(55.8607,-4.2871);
```

generated the map

```
googleMap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

built the marker

```
Marker secc =googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(SECC)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA))
            .title("SECC").snippet("Exhibition Way, Glasgow, G3 8YW\nSports: Boxing, Gymnastics, Judo, Netball, Wrestling, Weightlifting"));
```

set the on click listener to the map

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((OnMarkerClickListener)this);
```

set up the custom info box

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter()
        {
         @Override
         public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0)
            {
            return null;
             }

         public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
            {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker,null);

            TextView info=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

            info.setText("hello");
            return v;
             }
        });
```

and set up the click event

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
        {
          @Override
           public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
            {
              marker.showInfoWindow();
              return true;
            }
    });
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? The map loads and you can click on a marker to get a snippet but the custom info isn't displaying

edit to include manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.muc_coursework"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >    
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission
    android:name="org.me.myandroidstuff.mapstuff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission          
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.muc_coursework.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBFL6EfXODsfCxqyNktI5k9m03rygILej4"/>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
</application>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This below code may be helpful to you.

public class Stacky extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener {

static final LatLng SECC = new LatLng(55.8607,-4.2871);
    private GoogleMap mMap;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);


    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

     setUpMap();
       findSMSLocation();
    // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map      
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)   {                
            return null;
        }           

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info, null);

                TextView tvLat = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.info);     
                tvLat.setText("info");
                tvLat.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

            return v;
        }

    });


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


public void findSMSLocation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{   

          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(SECC).title("SECC").snippet("Exhibition Way, Glasgow, G3 8YW\nSports: Boxing, Gymnastics, Judo, Netball, Wrestling, Weightlifting"));

          mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SECC, 18.0f));

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2))
                .getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}



private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    return false;
}
```

}

You do not need to add  marker.showInfoWindow() into OnMarkerClickListner() interface.When you click n to marker then Custom window created and load with your custom textview.
[image: output given below]

Comment: Still not working! I've been checking the error logs, says "Failed to find provide for info com.google.android.gsf.gservices". The app is still running though could that be the problem?

Comment: could you show me your manifest.xml file and also your layout file?

Comment: sure, i edited it in, wouldnt fit in the comment box

Comment: and sorry it looks terrible can't seem to put xml files on this displaying properly like code

Comment: and also add your layout.xml file.

Comment: you must check about your Map key and also add SupportMapFragment into your layout.ml file like shown below:'<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>'

Comment: Wait I've found something different between my code and yours...

I checked the XML layout file and I have
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/> whereas you have maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: Also where the map is instantiated in the activity file I have 

'googleMap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();'

wheras you have.getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: When I try to change the activity file to match yours it has an error - The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: Have you added Support Library into your project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43426/discussion-between-c-mac-and-manish-patel)