# Google Maps: Multiple values in snippet

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When I make a marker, i need to add some custom properties that are not included in the actual `marker` object. I'm thinking of adding these custom properties all in the `snippet`, maybe an array or something.

However, the snippet can only take a string value, not an array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

yes inflate a custom layout to it and set values as you want!

[Custom infowindow in Google map android v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475059/custom-infowindow-in-google-map-android-v2)

[Displaying custom text in a map snippet, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647082/displaying-custom-text-in-a-map-snippet-android)

Comment: yes, i know that, but how do i put an array into a field that expects a string?